# I am trying to delete a specific task queue from GPC using nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to delete a specific task from my task queue using code from nodejs. i can't seem to find proper documentation on deleting a task. I only saw documentation on how to delete a queue. I tried the code below and it gives me an error.

```
delete = async (projectId) => {
    const location = "us-central1";
    const queue = this.queue_id;
    // Get the fully qualified path to the queue
    const name = client.queuePath(projectId, location, queue);

    try {
      const taskDelete = await client.deleteTask(name);
      console.log("delete initiated for project id: ", projectId);
      console.log(`deleted queue task: ${taskDelete}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

and i am getting eerror from console:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request.

 code: 3,
  details: 'Invalid resource field value in the request.',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

confused as I am new to GPC

thank you and I apologize for the bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you care calling [deleteTask](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/v2.CloudTasksClient.html#deleteTask) from [CloudTasksClient](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/v2.CloudTasksClient.html) which is the right approach.  However examine carefully the parameter you are passing to it.  It seems to require an object of the format:

```
{
   "name": "[projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/TASK_ID]"
}
```

You are passing a string (not an object) and the string is a queue resource and not a task resource.

I get the impression that what you want to code is:

```
const taskDelete = await client.deleteTask({
   "name": client.taskPath(projectId, location, queue, taskId)
});
```

Comment: I found the proper way to do it. this answer actually led me to it so thank you!

I needed to invoke auth.getclient() and once auth is done i could use this method (cloudtasks.projects.locations.queues.tasks.delete())

thank you for responding!